# Смешение прямой и косвенной речи (1)

Tags: прямая-речь

Прощение, по словам Кор, освободило ее от ее «трагического прошлого: «Я стала свободна от Освенцима, и я стала свободна от Менгеле».

Можно ли так оформить прямую речь?

Или правильно будет:

Прощение, по словам Кор, освободило ее от ее «трагического прошлого.

«Я стала свободна от Освенцима, и я стала свободна от Менгеле», - говорит она.

Comment: Если же вставка слов и сказал, и воскликнул, и спросил и т.п. после авторских слов невозможна или затруднительна, то двоеточие не ставится, например:
Ему все стало ясно.
–        Говорить нам больше не о чем.

Comment: Во втором варианте, Alex_ander, вставка слов _и сказала_ невозможна, и поэтому двоеточие ставить нельзя.

Answer (score 3):

Думаю, в исходном варианте достаточно закрыть кавычки после "прошлого": это разделит кратко процитированное выражение и полностью приведённую цитату.

Во втором варианте, закрыв кавычки после "прошлого", можно как оставить точку, так и поставить двоеточие; после этого с новой строки без кавычек привести прямую речь, начав с тире.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы так написала:

Прощение, по словам Кор, освободило ее от ее трагического прошлого: «Я стала свободна от Освенцима, и я стала свободна от Менгеле».

Обычное цитирование.

Пример:  В творчестве Блока существенную роль играло напряженное вглядывание в будущее: "Предчувствую Тебя. Года проходят мимо - Всё в облике одном предчувствую Тебя".